# Calculating sum of jobs processed every month using two tables

Tags: sql, join

I have these two tables:

1. TIME (this table contains the time_id which in turn gives the details like the day,month, year etc)

   ```
   |time_id|hour|day|month|year|
   _____________________________
   |1234   |1   |6  |9    |2013|
   _____________________________
   |1235   |2   |7  |9    |2013|
   _____________________________
   |1223   |2   |4  |8    |2014|
   _____________________________
   |1227   |2   |8  |8    |2014|
   ```
2. SUM_JOBS_PROCESSED (this table contains the time_id and the no of jobs processed for this particular time_id.)

   ```
   |time_id|sum_of_jobs_processed|  
   _______________________________
   |1234   |5              |
   _______________________________
   |1235   |6              |
   _______________________________
   |1223   |4              |
   _______________________________
   |1227   |4              |
   ```

I am trying to write a query which should display something like this

```
|month|year|sum_of_jobs_processed|
__________________________________
|9    |2013| 11                  |
__________________________________
|8    |2014| 8                   |
__________________________________
```

It should display total number of jobs processed for a month.

Could anyone please help me with these? I am able to find total number of jobs processed for a day, but number of jobs processed for a month, is not happening.

---

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also format your question to make it more readable.

Comment: SO far i have tried this and this gives me no of jobs processed per day                                                     select T2.month, T2.year, T1.sum_cites_found
from SUM_JOBS_PROCESSED T1
    inner join TIME T2 on
        T2.time_id = T1.time_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understood what you're trying, but I think this query should give you the desired result:

```
  SELECT t.month,
         t.year, 
         SUM(s.sum_of_jobs_processed)
    FROM bspm_dim_time t
    JOIN bspm_sum_jobs_day s
      ON t.time_id = s.time_id
GROUP BY t.month,
         t.year
ORDER BY t.year,
         t.month
```

[**Live DEMO.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/588ff/11)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT month,
           year,
           sum(sum_of_jobs_processed)
      FROM TIME
INNER JOIN SUM_JOBS_PROCESSED
        ON TIME.time_id = SUM_JOBS_PROCESSED.time_id
  GROUP BY month,
           year
  ORDER BY month,
           year
```

Mark as answer if correct.